# Winsock C++, faster way to see if port is available than using 'connect'?

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock

What's the fastest way to see if a TCP port on a remote computer is listening or is available?

After I do a `socket` call, the `select` function always returns `0`, whether or not the remote computer has port 43210 open or closed!

The test remote computer has its firewall turned on, but has port 43210 open (or closed) for this testing.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <mstcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")      // More than one instance overloaded function has C linkage

DWORD Tryselect()
{
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    INT recvbuflen = 4096;
    INT iResult;
    sockaddr_in clientService{};
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;

    // Create the socket (local)
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    timeval timeOut = { 0 };
    timeOut.tv_sec = 5;
    timeOut.tv_usec = 0; 
    fd_set fdset; 
    FD_ZERO(&fdset); 
    FD_SET(ConnectSocket, &fdset); 
    int iRet = select(0, NULL, &fdset, NULL, &timeOut);
    DWORD dwErrWSA = WSAGetLastError();    

    ULONG nInterfaceAddr = 0;
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.12", &nInterfaceAddr);
    clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = nInterfaceAddr;
    clientService.sin_port = htons(43210);
    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService));

    return 0;
}


int __cdecl main()
{
    Tryselect();
}
```

I also tried `WSAConnectByName`, but I could not get the timeout to even work correctly.

Comment: Is the remote machine behind a firewall?  Normally, if the port is reachable but not listening, you get `WSAECONNREFUSED` straightaway.

Comment: your code is waiting the remote side to write something. But only some servers write something in socket when you connect to them.

Comment: @KoVadim I don't see anything in the code posted that's doing that.

Comment: When the `connect` is run, it takes 21 seconds before it times out. That's why I'm trying the select statement to see if it can do a write in the select statement.

Comment: And what error code do you get when it does?  Start analysing and stop guessing.

Comment: @Paul 3'rd argument of select.

Comment: Even if port is open, `fdset.fd_count` = 0, `iRet` = 0, and `dwErrWSA` = 0. BUT, the port isn't used until the `connect` statement.

Comment: Imagine that `select` did check whether a port on another computer was listening without fully connecting to it (it could for example send `RST` in step 3 of the TCP 3-way handshake instead of `ACK`).  How would you tell it what remote computer and port to check?  Your code doesn't even name the remote IP address or remote port number until after `select` has already returned!!!!!

Comment: If you are able to have a program running on the remote computer, you could ask that program to call `bind()` on the port and then report back to you whether the call succeeded or not.  (Note that once the call to `bind()` succeeds, the port is by definition no longer available, so your program would either want to make use of the bound socket, or close it)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner simply `bind()`'ing a port does not mean it is actually listening for connections. You need `listen()` for that.

Comment: "After I do a `socket` call, the `select` function always returns 0". Of course it does. You haven't initiated any I/O, or anything that could receive it. Do you mean `connect()`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'd think that if you can `bind()` to a port, that indicates the port was definitely *not* listening for connections, no?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It depends on the parameters of the `bind()`, and the status of the port on all of the available interfaces. The port might not be used *exclusively* across all interfaces, so it *could* be listening on only a particular interface and yet `bind()` *could* still still succeed if other interfaces were able to be bound. In that situation, if you are already running code locally anyway, it might make more sense to just enumerate Windows' local TCP tables looking for the port's existing usage, rather than trying to actively `bind()` the port (and thus taking up its resources).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What's the fastest way to see if a TCP port on a remote computer is listening or is available?

There is only 1 way to test the availability of a TCP port - attempt to `connect()` (or equivalent) to the port, and handle any errors that may occur.

> After I do a `socket` call, the `select` function always returns `0`, whether or not the remote computer has port 43210 open or closed!

That is because your test code is wrong, for a number of reasons:

- You are not initializing the Winsock library, which will cause `socket()` and `select()` to fail with a `WSANOTINITIALISED` error, but you are not handling that condition. On Windows, you MUST call `WSAStartup()` before calling any other Winsock functions (except for `WSAGetLastError()`).  This is not required on other platforms.
- You are calling `connect()` **after** calling `select()`, so there is no activity for `select()` to report status for.  You need to swap the order of these 2 functions.
- You are using the socket in **blocking mode**, which means `connect()` will not exit until the operation is finished, whether it is successful or failed.  Thus, there is no opportunity to use `select()`.  To use a timeout with `connect()`, you MUST either:

  - put the socket into **non-blocking mode** first, then call `connect()` (or equivalent) and make sure it fails with a `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error, and then use `select()` (or equivalent) to wait for the connect operation to finish or timeout.
  - call `connect()` in a separate thread than your timeout wait. If the wait times out, you can `closesocket()` the socket to abort the `connect()`. On other platforms, `close()` alone is not guaranteed to abort a blocking `connect()`, so you would need to `shutdown()` the socket first.
- You are using `select()` to detect only if the `connect()` operation succeeded, but not detect if it failed.  If it did fail, your code would never know that, and keep waiting until the timeout elapsed. On Windows, you need to use `select()`'s `writefds` parameter to handle the success case, and the `exceptfds` parameter to handle the failure case.  This is different than other platforms, which only use the `writefds` parameter for both cases, and then you would use `getsockopt(SO_ERROR)` to differentiate success from failure.
- You are leaking the `SOCKET`. You need to call `closesocket()` when you are done using it.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <mstcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int Tryselect()
{
    int iErr = 0;

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        iErr = WSAGetLastError();
    }
    else
    {
        u_long mode = 1;
        int iResult = ioctlsocket(ConnectSocket, FIONBIO, &mode);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            iErr = WSAGetLastError();
        }
        else
        {
            sockaddr_in clientService{};
            clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
            inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.168.1.12", &clientService.sin_addr);
            clientService.sin_port = htons(43210);

            iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService));
            if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                iErr = WSAGetLastError();
                if (iErr == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                {
                    timeval timeOut = { 0 };
                    timeOut.tv_sec = 5;
                    timeOut.tv_usec = 0; 

                    fd_set wset, eset; 
                    FD_ZERO(&wset); FD_SET(ConnectSocket, &wset); 
                    FD_ZERO(&eset); FD_SET(ConnectSocket, &eset); 

                    iResult = select(0, NULL, &wset, &eset, &timeOut);

                    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
                    {
                        iErr = WSAGetLastError();
                    }
                    else if (iResult == 0)
                    {
                        iErr = WSAETIMEDOUT;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        iErr = 0;
                        if (FD_ISSET(ConnectSocket, &eset))
                        {
                            int size = sizeof(iErr);
                            getsockopt(ConnectSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &iErr, &size);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    }

    return iErr;
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    int err = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsa);
    if (err != 0) ...
    
    err = Tryselect();
    ...
    
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Remy, this is awesome! Thank you so much for showing me what's going on and making sense of it all! The code works excellent! I just had to add a 5th param to getsockopt.

Comment: @JeffR "*I just had to add a 5th param to getsockopt*" - good catch. I have fixed it